# Keycloak Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I have integrated keycloak with my angularJS app.While I running the app after login page, The browser console showing.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.7:8080/auth/realms/app1/protocol/openid-connect/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://192.168.1.7:8000', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://192.168.1.7:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Did you found the solution for this. I have the same issue, even after setting Web Origins as *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `Web Origins` property for your client in the KC Web Console.

Comment: Could you try with `*` just to see if it works then ?

Comment: It looks like your Web Origins is set to `*, http://192.168.1.7:8000` but you can only have one value here. It is NOT a comma separated list. If you want to add multiple values then you must add a new line. Also, your ports don't match up. You have 8080 in one location and 8000 in another. Try to use ONLY `*`.